# Unable to move checkboxes to right

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am unable to move all checkboxes right in one vertical line. I have no idea how can i do it. Because float:right added to .checkbox moves all content to right.

You can take a look for better understanding of my problem on site  (it loads slowly because of embed videos and big images) Code may look messy i am learning sorry.

```css
body:not(#foo) input[type='checkbox'] {
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox,
.radio {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox::-moz-selection,
.radio::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent;
}

.checkbox::selection,
.radio::selection {
  background: transparent;
}

.checkbox input+span,
.radio input+span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 .5em 9px 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.checkbox input+span::after,
.radio input+span::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s, -webkit-transform .2s;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .checkbox:hover input+span,
  .radio:hover input+span {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  }
}

.checkbox input:active+span,
.radio input:active+span {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.checkbox input:focus+span,
.radio input:focus+span {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px lightblue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px lightblue;
}

.checkbox input:checked+span::after,
.radio input:checked+span::after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.checkbox input,
.radio input {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox input+span {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.checkbox input+span::after {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.radio input+span {
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.radio input+span::after {
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: .65em;
  width: .75em;
  height: .75em;
}

.radio input:checked+span::after {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<!-- BEGIN - FILTERS -->
<div class="indexfilters">
  <div class="border">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <i class="fas fa-child"></i><a class="icontext">Starostlivosť o deti</a>
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
        <span></span>
        </label><br>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i><a class="icontext">Zdravá strava</a>
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
        <span></span>
        </label><br>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <i class="fas fa-book"></i><a class="icontext">Recepty</a>
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
        <span></span>
        </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <i class="fas fa-crosshairs"></i><a class="icontext">Potravinové podvody</a>
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
        <span></span>
        </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <i class="fas fa-ban"></i><a class="icontext">Jedy v potrave</a>
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
        <span></span>
        </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <i class="fas fa-industry"></i><a class="icontext">Potravinový priemysel</a>
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
        <span></span>
        </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <i class="fas fa-recycle"></i><a class="icontext">Recyklovanie</a>
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
        <span></span>
        </label>
    <div class="divbtnfilter">
      <a class="btnfilter">Filtrovať</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is what you're looking for:

```
.border {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.border>.checkbox {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
}

.checkbox a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.divbtnfilter {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```css
body:not(#foo) input[type='checkbox'] {
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox,
.radio {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox::-moz-selection,
.radio::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent;
}

.checkbox::selection,
.radio::selection {
  background: transparent;
}

.checkbox input+span,
.radio input+span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 .5em 9px 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.checkbox input+span::after,
.radio input+span::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s, -webkit-transform .2s;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .checkbox:hover input+span,
  .radio:hover input+span {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  }
}

.checkbox input:active+span,
.radio input:active+span {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.checkbox input:focus+span,
.radio input:focus+span {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px lightblue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px lightblue;
}

.checkbox input:checked+span::after,
.radio input:checked+span::after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.checkbox input,
.radio input {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox input+span {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.checkbox input+span::after {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.radio input+span {
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.radio input+span::after {
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: .65em;
  width: .75em;
  height: .75em;
}

.radio input:checked+span::after {
  background: black;
}

.border {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.border>.checkbox {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
}

.checkbox a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.divbtnfilter {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="indexfilters">
  <div class="border">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <i class="fa fa-child"></i><a class="icontext">Starostlivosť o deti</a>
      <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
      
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i><a class="icontext">Zdravá strava</a>
      <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <i class="fa fa-book"></i><a class="icontext">Recepty</a>
      <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i><a class="icontext">Potravinové podvody</a>
      <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <i class="fa fa-ban"></i><a class="icontext">Jedy v potrave</a>
      <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <i class="fa fa-industry"></i><a class="icontext">Potravinový priemysel</a>
      <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <i class="fa fa-recycle"></i><a class="icontext">Recyklovanie</a>
      <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <div class="divbtnfilter">
      <a class="btnfilter">Filtrovať</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a side-note, your markup and CSS are far from optimal.

---

Here's an easier to maintain version of your code (as per comments):

```js
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".checkboxes a"), function(element){
 element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log(element.innerHTML + ' checked: '+!element.nextElementSibling.checked)
 });
});
```

```css
body:not(#foo) input[type='checkbox'] {
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkboxes label,
.radio {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkboxes label::-moz-selection,
.radio::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent;
}

.checkboxes label::selection,
.radio::selection {
  background: transparent;
}

.checkboxes input+span,
.radio input+span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 .5em 9px 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.checkboxes input+span::after,
.radio input+span::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s, -webkit-transform .2s;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .checkboxes label:hover input+span,
  .radio:hover input+span {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  }
}

.checkboxes input:active+span,
.radio input:active+span {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.checkboxes input:focus+span,
.radio input:focus+span {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px lightblue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px lightblue;
}

.checkboxes input:checked+span::after,
.radio input:checked+span::after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.checkboxes input,
.radio input {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkboxes input+span {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.checkboxes input+span::after {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.radio input+span {
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.radio input+span::after {
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: .65em;
  width: .75em;
  height: .75em;
}

.radio input:checked+span::after {
  background: black;
}

.checkboxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.checkboxes>label {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
}

.checkboxes a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="indexfilters">
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <label>
      <i class="fa fa-child"></i><a>Starostlivosť o deti</a>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i><a>Zdravá strava</a>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <i class="fa fa-book"></i><a>Recepty</a>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i><a>Potravinové podvody</a>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <i class="fa fa-ban"></i><a>Jedy v potrave</a>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <i class="fa fa-industry"></i><a>Potravinový priemysel</a>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <i class="fa fa-recycle"></i><a class="icontext">Recyklovanie</a>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <div class="divbtnfilter">
      <a class="btnfilter">Filtrovať</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I did:

- rather than adding same class to all children I added a class to the parent and removed the class from children, updating the CSS
- removed all duplicate ids,
- removed similar `onclick` and added it with a simple script (the script should be run on DOM.ready event)

There's a lot to read and learn on coding best practices but you should probably start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_coding_practices).

Comment: Thanks but i need them on the right side. Because on the left side are icons.

Comment: No this moves everything right and then are my icons not in vertical line. Its really stupid situation :D I use alredy made checkboxes and didnt realized what i done.

Comment: Currently, your question is unclear. Please edit it so it becomes clear what is the desired output. Consider adding an image if you feel like your web development terminology or English language level are not enabling you to fully explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Pictures added :) site is actually not responsive maybe is different in your browser. And yes my dev and english skill are not very god.

Comment: And yes its not very well coded its my first/second site.

Comment: @Durinko, I believe my last attempt should do what you want. If it doesn't update the [mcve] with more details so it matches your project. In its current form, it's minimal, but it's not complete.

Comment: @Durinko, I updated. Please note I removed the `<br>`s from your markup. I also had to replace `.fas` with `.fa` to display the fontAwesome icons here, which is probably not necessary in your project.

Comment: Thanks that is awesome :) and sorry for me. I am totaly wasted from this.
And to this "As a side-note, your markup and CSS are far from optimal."
What u mean like when i make it responsive and fast loading is unpublishable?

Comment: Ideally, code should be maintainable. In principle, you should try to write your code so anytime you want modify something you only need to modify it in one place. As an example, I will update your snippet with an easier to maintain version. Another ***big*** problem is you have duplicate ids.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This didn't work for the asker, but I'm keeping this because it might be useful for others.

Your problem is that your `checkbox` class encompasses the name of the checkbox too, not only the checkbox itself. Move your `<input>` into a separate class and then only move those to the right.

```
<label class="checkbox"> <!-- Outer container -->
    <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i><a class="icontext">Zdravá strava</a> <!-- Text -->
    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');"> <!-- Checkbox -->
    <span></span>
</label>
```

Comment: <input class="moved" id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="console.log('changed');">

.moved {
float:right;
}

Not working :/

Comment: Huh. I don't know then, sorry. Keep experimenting with that concept, maybe?